# SSH Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified

Tags: ssh

From my Windows PC in command line (`cmd.exe`) I am connecting to a remote high performance computing cluster (RedHat 7 from my windows cmd terminal) and would like to open Firefox for uploading some data.

I connect to the cluster using,

**ssh -Y mylogin@myremote.server.fr**

In order to run Firefox I run the following commands,

**module load firefox**

**firefox &**

and get an error,

**Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified**

I have tried using the following commands but they don't work,

**export DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"**

or

**export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:10.0"**

Looking forward.

Comment: Please try `ssh -X -Y user@host`. I don't think `Y` alone is enough.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the same error. Seems like there is a solution to this (here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356425/error-cannot-open-display-localhost0-0-trying-to-open-firefox-from-centos-6) but it's not working on my windows cmd terminal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Windows by default does not include an X11 server to enable X11 forwarding. I might be wrong though. You cannot forward X11 applications without it. Check this for possible solutions:

- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242
- https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx
- https://wiki.iihe.ac.be/Use_X11_forwarding_with_WSL

Comment: So I installed Cygwin/X (from http://x.cygwin.com/) and then logged in again with ssh -X -Y mylogin@myremote.server.fr. But I still get the same error message (no DISPLAY environment variable specified) when I try to start firefox.

Comment: Try using `putty` instead: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html - make sure X forwarding is enabled in an SSH session options.

Comment: Good thing is I could connect with Putty and the error message is slightly different. It now says, ' cannot open display: localhost:12.0'. I also tried export DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"  and export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:10.0" but they don't work.

Comment: I got something new. PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused. Error: cannot open display: localhost:14.0

Comment: Your X11 server on Windows should tell you what is right display value, you cannot choose arbitrary value there. If you would run `xterm` in your cygwin, then you can see value with `echo $DISPLAY`, DISPLAY value is automatically passed to remote SSH host if you request X11 forwarding with `-Y` or `-X`. The remote host can of course disable X11Forwarding completely or for specific user.

Comment: I think I am a bit confused with Putty and Cygwin. I got some success with Putty so can we move in this direction. Now I configure Putty by enabling the X forwarding in the SSH session options. I keep the Display option blank and move ahead with the login. After I login, I execute 'module load firefox' and 'firefox &' and then there is a long wait and then I get the firefox browser but it fails with an error window that says 'Putty Fatal Error: Netwrok Error: Software caused connection abort'. Is this because of a slow connection?